# When is a property 'time dependent' or constant?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, time, terminology

If we take an object going through motion in an experiment where it's mass is not changed in each run we would say it's mass is 'constant' and 'does not depend on time', taking the derivative of it's momentum $mv$ provides us with no issue.

If I defined a strange system where every $10$ seconds I added a mass of $10kg$, (but in the meantime there is no gradual change in mass),to this object, would it's mass be technically time dependent?

Looking at it's momentum I would get a piecewise function for each mass, taking this derivative gives another piecewise function whose value at each interval is of the same form $m_ia$ that I would get if I took the derivative for completely constant $m$.

If I had another scenario where it's mass can be changed at any time, and has a multi-variable function for momentum $f(m,v)=mv$ would $m$ be time dependent, I assume not but the first situation is not that different to the second.

Would the mass be 'time dependent' in the first, and 'constant' in the second?

Answer (score 2):

> If I defined a strange system where every 10 seconds I added a mass of 10kg, (but in the meantime there is no gradual change in mass),to this object, would it's mass be technically time dependent?

Yes, it is time dependent. The time dependence can be written in terms of step functions like:
$$
m(t) = m_0 + 10\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta(t - 10n)\;.
$$

The mass looks like a staircase in time, stepping up every ten seconds by ten kilograms.

The mass is constant over the interval between the steps, but it is not constant for all times. At each step the time-derivative of the mass is a delta function:
$$
\frac{dm}{dt} = 10\sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(t - 10n)\;,
$$
which is zero everywhere there is not a step up, but infinite at the steps (using the usual loose physics definition of a delta "function").

Comment: Could we also express it as a piecewise function, so the derivative is also a piecewise function (where $m$ is continuous).

Comment: You could smooth out the step function if you want. Really, *you* can do anything you want, since it is your hypothetical question. What you describe in your original post sounded like a sudden increase in the mass, in which case the mass would not be continuous. But you could replace the step function with some kind of smoother function (e.g., fermi function), sure, and that would make the mass function continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This mass would be time-dependent, and you can express it as follows:

$$m(t) = m_0 + 10t$$

However, if you know the values, you can also model it as a bunch of items with constant mass. generally, I think the former is cleaner, but it's up to you and whatever works best given the information you have to do the computation. An expression or quality is time-dependent when said expression depends on time. Oftentimes (e.g. in this case), you can choose how to express your system best keeping in mind what your goal is.

Comment: note $10(t)$ denotes multiplication in this case whereas $m(t)$ denotes t dependence

Comment: the thing with this system is that for example at t=5 it will still be 10kg but at t=10 it will be 20kg, so it's not precisely a linear slope, sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: What @user1007028 described in their post is not constant, but also not linear. Rather it is step-function-like increase. You wrote down a linear function... Not sure if they update their post or not. (This is why I quote the OP in my response).

Comment: @hft my fault, I should have explained better.

Comment: the general concept still holds that depending on the details of the system, you can determine if something is time-dependent or not (sometimes) and take different approaches to solving your problem. i say sometimes because there can be cases where you cannot do anything other than work with the time dependence. it really just depends on your problem, but you asked about the definition of time dependence, and this quite literally means when a quantity depends on time. if you have a more specific question about your problem maybe ask that !

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber no problem, thanks for the answer, I've cancelled out that downvote that someone gave you.

Comment: also hft is right about the step function as opposed to linear function - i dont know if the post was updated or if i just misread, but hope you get the picture @user1007028

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber you can remove your "note" comment (the first comment)

Answer (score 1):

A rocket is an example of an object commonly understood through the concept of time-dependent mass. As it burns its fuel, it loses mass. This leads to a time-dependent acceleration (assuming constant thrust). The [rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) is the result.